# ok so im trying to read the output of a command

Tags: bash

```
echo -en "date: "
read sdate
mdate="date -d '${sdate} 00:00:00' +%s "
udate(){ 
$mdate 
}
udate
```

output

```
root@Xanarchy:/cnc# bash date
date: 01-01-2000
date: extra operand ‘+%s’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Comment: What you're doing there falls squarely in ["How can we run a command stored in a variable?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373). Here, you'd be best off just spelling the command out in the function instead of using a variable. But you're not reading the output of the command there, at all. You'd need `output=$(date ...)` or so for that.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and i) ask a question; ii) explain what you are trying to do and how it fails and iii) give a descriptive title: remember that the title is all people see when looking at the home page, so if you don't explain what the question is in the title, people will ignore it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -en "date: "
read sdate
mdate=(date -d "${sdate} 00:00:00" +%s)
udate(){
"${mdate[@]}"
}
udate
```

Using a string makes this unnecessarily complicated. Using an array is much simpler.

`01-01-2000` is illegal input for `date`. You need `2000-01-01`.